# extract from a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

This is my principal data :

```
1    Cl1  28    2750 2015-05-16 Marseille        S7
2    Cl1  27    2570 2015-06-03 Marseille        S7
3 Cl1000  24    1950 2015-07-05 Marseille       S17
4 Cl1000  17    1400 2016-01-09 Marseille       S17
5  Cl104  29    2680 2015-01-02  Grenoble        S3
6  Cl110  29    2660 2016-02-02    Calais        S2
```

I want to extract the quantities Qte per month, of the year 2015 and Typologies S1 and S2.

```
df<-sqldf("select Qte, typologie  from 
          where ='S1, S2'
          And data_achat.year = 2015'
          Group by date_achat.month  
           ")
```

I get Null as a result.

I want also to visualise and compare quantities per month, which plot should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what is wanted is the sum of `Qte` by `Client` and month for those rows for which the year is `2015` and the `Typologie` is `S1` or `S2` we provide some test data in the Note below that is in reproducible form.

Since there was no row for which year is `2015` and `Typologie` is `S1` or `S2` in the data shown in the question we added a 7th row for which this holds.

Note that the year is the first 4 characters of the date and the month is the 2 characters starting at position 6 of the date.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select Client, substr(Date_achat, 6, 2) month, sum(Qte) Qte, typologie
       from AllInfosClients 
       where Typologie in ('S1', 'S2') and substr(Date_achat, 1, 4) = '2015'
       group by 1, 2")
```

giving:

```
  Client month Qte Typologie
1  Cl110    02  29        S2
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "
Client Qte Montant Date_achat     Ville Typologie
1    Cl1  28    2750 2015-05-16 Marseille        S7
2    Cl1  27    2570 2015-06-03 Marseille        S7
3 Cl1000  24    1950 2015-07-05 Marseille       S17
4 Cl1000  17    1400 2016-01-09 Marseille       S17
5  Cl104  29    2680 2015-01-02  Grenoble        S3
6  Cl110  29    2660 2016-02-02    Calais        S2
7  Cl110  29    2660 2015-02-02    Calais        S2"
AllInfosClients <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Comment: Start a fresh R session and then copy and paste the code in the Note at the end into the R console and then copy and paste the code in the body of the answer and you will get the same output as shown in the answer.